# Parallel computation

Tags: multithreading, visual-studio-2012, parallel-processing, thread-safety, ilnumerics

All,

I would like to use Ilnumerics for computations to be made in parallel. They are completely uncoupled. I would need it for 
1) random restarts for an optimiser (especially stochastic optimiser, e.g. simulated annealing) : solving the same optimisation problems starting in parallel from different points:
e.g.: argmin_x f(x) starting from x0_h h = 1,2,..,K
2) same optimisation to be run over a sets of uncoupled data; as an example, consider the following unconstrained optimisation problem:
given a function f (R^d x R^p) --> R of x \in R^d and p parameters p\in R^d
solve argmin_x f(x,p_h),  h = 1, 2, ..., K.

I hope the notation is clear enough.

Would it be possible to run this loop in parallel, executing everytime some lambda expression involving ILnumerics objects and leveraging on multicores architectures?

Thanks in advance, as usual,

GL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends: ILNumerics automatically parallelizes mathematical expressions like

```
C = A + B[":;2"] / 0.4 * pinv(C) ...
```

By attempting to run multiple instances of such expressions in parallel, using multiple threads from the thread pool, you would end up producing a lot of contention by too many threads competing for the CPU time slots. In the result your algorithm may runs slower than without parallelizing it.

So, in that case you may disable the internal automatic parallelization ILNumerics does transparently for you:

```
Settings.MaxNumberThreads = 1;
```

Expressions like the one above will get evaluated within a single thread afterwards. However, now you are responsible for distributing computational tasks over multiple threads. And moreover, you will have to lock your arrays accordingly - because ILNumerics is not thread safe in general! This allows you to write concurrently to your output arrays but also brings the burdon of having to implement a correct locking scheme...